# Google Contextual Gmail Gadget in GAM 2.0 not triggering

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have a Google Apps Mail Contextual Gadget which worked fine in the previous version of GAM (Google Apps Marketplace) with the manifest.xml file on the vendor account. I am now filling out the COB form for GAM2, but the app never triggers in my gmail account when activated via the **Test Install Flow** button.

I am using a Custom Extractor:

#### customExtractor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OpenCOBData id="testCustomExtractor">

  <ExtractorSpec platform="gmail" language="en">

    <Search input_type="text">
      <Pattern input_fields="from_email,body"> 
        <![CDATA[(?P<sender_name>.*)]]> 
      </Pattern> 
    </Search>

    <Response platform="gmail" format="cardgadget">
      <Output name="sender_name">{@__FROM_PERSONAL__}</Output>
      <Output name="sender_email">{@__FROM_ADDRESS__}</Output>
      <Output name="recipient_name">{@__TO_PERSONAL__}</Output>
      <Output name="recipient_email">{@__TO_ADDRESS__}</Output>
      <Output name="message_id">{@__MESSAGE_ID__}</Output>
    </Response>

  </ExtractorSpec>

</OpenCOBData>
```

The ID for this extractor on the Google Apps Extension Console is **500140453954**, making the url **500140453954:testCustomExtractor**

#### Screenshot of GAM2 Form

[image: Screenshot of GAM form]

Is there any obvious mistake I'm making here?
I have tested viewing the gadget with both admin and regular users, the gadget was written by the admin account. The custom extractor is also owned by the admin account if this has any impact.

**Another question:** As the manifest.xml file is now obsolete due to the form, is there a different place where reasons for permissions can be given?

---

#### image of new gadget using @koma's url and pre-canned message extractor.

[image]

Comment: did you create a project in cloud.google.com ? Add the market place SDK ? Create a chrome webstore extension ?

Comment: @koma, project was created in the new console.developers.google.com, using the Google MarketPlace SDK, I'm not sure about the Chrome Webstore Extension

Comment: @koma, did you mean the Chrome Webstore Extension as an alternative, as I am considering that as my best option now.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Webstore application is a requirement to deploy Google Apps marketplace listings. The manifest indicates that this is a Google Apps marketplace application by setting the container and the project Id :

"container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "projectNumber"

see [the docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing).

You must enable the marketplace SDK in your project and setup the required scopes there and configure the COB extension (== the contextual gadget).

I would start off simple with a canned extractor.

Once you have everything configured, you can test the install flow from the marketplace SDK configuration. The gadget should show up.

I am not sure if it is possible to get a custom extractor to work with the new marketplace listings. A better road may be to only extract the message Id using the canned extractor and then make calls to the [new Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) to retrieve any additional info about the message at hand. You will need the additional scope configured in that case.

Comment: I have already tested the Install Flow; the SSO part of my application works fine but the gadget never triggers. But I will see if configuring the chrome webstore application helps.

Comment: try removing the custom extractor and use only the canned extractor for messageId and use this simple gadget URL to test with : randstadsourcing.vps.koma.be/testgadget.xml ; I just did exactly that for a client without any issues.

Comment: I've created a plain new gadget using your gadget spec and the message_id extractor, still no luck. I'll add a screenshot in my question of my COB data

Comment: it's working suddenly, initially I was getting a `http get cancelled` on your url but the gadget is showing. Thank you, I will try applying it to my gadget now.

Comment: no luck on my own gadget spec, were any previous features like oauthpopup, osapi, rpc etc removed? is there even a chance that the contents of my spec file can prevent google from loading it when it's triggered?

Comment: I am not sure if the custom extractors still work for the new marketplace listings. Osapi, signed requests and the Oauth container still work, but I would only catch the message Id and try to obtain the other info about the msg using the gmail api.